# how to pass date value into my url using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
htmlfile=urllib.request.urlopen("https://hermes.goibibo.com/hotels/v2/search/data/v3/6771549831164675055/{pickUpDate}/{dropOffDate}/1-1_0?s=popularity&cur=INR&f={}&pid=0".format(pickUpDate=pickUpDate, dropOffDate=dropOffDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three `{}` pairs but 2 values in your URL. You need to match the `{}` pairs with the given values.

For instance:

```
"{v1} is {v2}. {v3}".format(v1="Cat", v2="Animal", v3="Absolutely!")
```

the string is **"Cat is Animal. Absolutely!"**

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your string you have `"..INR&f={}&pid=0".format()`.

If this is not a placeholder into which you want to place text via `.format()`, then change it to have double moustache brackets.  i.e:

`"...INR&f={{}}&pid=0".format()`

This will tell `.format()` that you really just want the brackets to exist there as a string

So, in general:

```
>>"{x}: {}".format(x="Hello")
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

but

```
>>"{x}: {{}}".format(x="Hello")
'Hello: {}'
```

Answer (score -1):

htmlfile=urllib.request.urlopen("https://hermes.goibibo.com/hotels/v2/search/data/v3/6771549831164675055/"+pickUpDate+"/"+dropOffDate+"/1-1_0?s=popularity&cur=INR&f={}&pid=0")